# Custom Client Server for small company to replace Access Database

Tags: microsoft-access

I have been to find a solution that would require little developer skills after job is complete. This is to be a client server app that can also generate reports.

The scenario is the Office worker generated a new work order which contains one or more work items to investigate.
Tech goes to site investigates mechanical issue(s) on item at a time.
As the tech find issues they are to update the nature of the issue with notes and parts that would need replacing.
This info needs to go back to office to give the client a fast update of the nature of a problem and a quote to the cost of a repair.

Is there software out there that can support form with subforms for under $200 CAD / month?

Also going forward much more functions ablity will be added such as time tracking.

I think [Caspio](https://www.caspio.com/) can do it but this project is certain to go over the limit of 40 data forms / reports.

Is there software that makes sense in this case or does it need to build out manually?

Below are a few screenshot of the idea that communicates much more.
[image]
Labor Details
[image]
Parts used
[image]

Comment: Looks like this project is going to move ahead with FileMaker.
consider nuBuilder Forte with Wordpress for a bit. nuBuilder Forte does not seem the be there yet with professional level tools.